# UIView not handling touches

Tags: iphone, uikit, uiview, statusbar, uiapplication

I have set my status bar hidden in my Application.
 [application setStatusBarHidden:YES];

I have added an UIView on the window as a subview at 0,0,320,40. But I am not able to get touches on my View ?

But if i am changing the 'Y' position like 0,30,320,40 its working fine.

What is the problem ???

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `isUserInteractionEnabled` on the view.  Some views, like `UIImageView`, disable that by default.

Comment: Its not handling touches in the simulator, but working fine on the device.

Answer (score 1):

check if there is a sub-view blocking it

Comment: But if i am changing the 'Y' position like 0,30,320,40 its working fine.